# I can not edit the listview need onContextItemSelected

Tags: android, listview

```
@Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // AdapterContextMenuInfo info=
        // (AdapterContextMenuInfo)item.getMenuInfo();
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AdapterContextMenuInfo info = (AdapterContextMenuInfo) item
                .getMenuInfo();

        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.menu_delete:

            this.results.remove(info.position);
            ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter);
            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;

        case R.id.menu_editar:

            this.results.add(info.position, null);
            ArrayAdapter<String> mAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, results);
            setListAdapter(mAdapter1);
            mAdapter1.notifyDataSetChanged();
            return true;
        default:

            return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
```

I'm trying to edit a trip and stored in a listView, I manage to delete but not edit.

I would appreciate any help or example.

Thanks for your help

Comment: you have not use break statement.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying and that's not the problem.

Comment: What is a stack trace?

Comment: now I delete an item, but I need to edit